# GWT: RequestFactory and ListDataProvider type error

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I'm trying to make a generic method to get some data with RequestFactory. 
I have a method getData that executes fire on a Request in order to  get a list of items(generics) 
The problem is when I try to assign the returned List arg0 to my ListDataProvider I get a type error.

```
private ListDataProvider<T> dataProvider; 
. 
. 
. 
. 
public <T> void getData(Request<List<T>> specificRequest) { 
                specificRequest.fire(new Receiver<List<T>>() { 
                        @Override 
                        public void onSuccess(List<T> arg0) { 
                                assignDataProvider(arg0); 
                        } 
                }); 
                return ; 
} 

public <T> void assignDataProvider(List<T> arg0) { 
                this.dataProvider.setList(arg0); 
                //The method setList(List<T>) in the type ListDataProvider<T> is not 
applicable for the arguments (List<T>) 
                this.dataProvider= new ListDataProvider<T>(arg0); 
                //Type mismatch: cannot convert from 
com.google.gwt.view.client.ListDataProvider<T> to 
com.google.gwt.view.client.ListDataProvider<T> 
}
```

How can I use the data I get from arg0 so I can assign it to my ListDataProvider?

Comment: What error are you getting? Always provide error stack trace with code.

Comment: The error is:
public <T> void assignDataProvider(List<T> arg0) { 
      this.dataProvider.setList(arg0); 
      this.dataProvider= new ListDataProvider<T>(arg0); 
                
}

when I use: this.dataProvider.setList(arg0); 
The method setList(List<T>) in the type ListDataProvider<T> is not 
applicable for the arguments (List<T>) 

when I use : this.dataProvider= new ListDataProvider<T>(arg0); 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from 
com.google.gwt.view.client.ListDataProvider<T> to 
com.google.gwt.view.client.ListDataProvider<T>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't get error on the declaration of dataProvider type T is defined as a parameter in a class declaration.
If so you should remove  from method declarations.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you I removed the <T> from the methods declaration and it worked